# warnings filter ignores 'once'

Tags: python, warnings

It seems I can only set the warnings module to all or nothing, and I'm trying to determine why.

At the top of my script I'm using either

`warnings.simplefilter(action='once')`
or
`warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')`

When I set the action to `ignore` it hides all warnings as expected. However, when I set the action to `once` it prints the warning every time my function is called (in a loop, from another function inside the script). Ex:

> /home/ec2-user/predict_evaluate/gt_ops.py:203:
>   UserWarning: Too many positive examples of class {label} to balance
>   dataset! Try increasing predict limit.   warnings.warn(msg)
>   /home/ec2-user/predict_evaluate/gt_ops.py:203:
>   UserWarning: Too many positive examples of class {label} to balance
>   dataset! Try increasing predict limit.   warnings.warn(msg)
>   /home/ec2-user/predict_evaluate/gt_ops.py:203:
>   UserWarning: Too many positive examples of class {label} to balance
>   dataset! Try increasing predict limit.   warnings.warn(msg)

What is/are the reason(s) that would prevent `action=once` from working?

Comment: Is your script/file being called multiple times? It's hard to tell what the issue is without a code example.

Comment: It's only being called once. It's going to be very difficult to strip it down to post a minimal example, but will try to work on that now. Was wondering if there are known general cases that would cause this to occur. I guess running the script multiple times would definitely be one reason.